# How to add extra information to IdentityUser and extend UserManager methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using Asp.net mvc IdentityUser class to store users in my application. In database there is AspNetUsers table and all users are unqiue with email. But now i needed to add extra Customer information to ApplicationUser class. Now on users with email can be both for Customer A and Customer B with same email.

My ApplicationUser class is like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

But i couldnt find a way to extend UserManager and change the methods as i needed.

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> AddAccount(string email, int customerId)
{
    // Asp.net User
    var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
    string password = Membership.GeneratePassword(5, 1);
    if (user == null)
    {
        user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = email, Email = email, CustomerId = customerId };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I need to extend the method FindByEmailAsync that it does not only takes email parameter, it also takes CustomerId as a parameter.

I need FindByEmail(string email, int customerId) and i dont know how to do it?

Comment: why you can not override this method

Comment: @erdiyılmaz if you overriding the method must have the same input params

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this you must create `MyUserManager` that inherits from `UserManager`. Then Add Method `FindByEmailAndId([your params])`.

Like this:

```
public class MyUserManager<TUser> : UserManager<TUser>
{
    public async Task<TUser> FindByEmailAsync(string email, int customerId)
    {
        //your code.
    }
}
```

But i don't understand why? if you creating a user one or two of your params must be unic. then why dont use this param?